# Authors separated by different keyword in bibliography

Tags: latex

I'm having an internationalization problem with latex.

In the .bib files authors are separated by the keyword 'and'.

In the file generated by latex the authors in the citations are also separated by 'and'. As the document I am producing is in Portuguese I needed authors to be separeted by the 'e' keyword instead.

I am using babel package in Portuguese but it makes no difference on the citations.

Any lights on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a bibliography style and/or package that supports non-English keywords as well. Try the `babelbib` or the `biblatex` package.